# creating a list in R with data frame having common values in single matching against the other

Tags: sql, r, list

I have a data frame having two columns, I want to create an extra column/replace the second column with LIST of items having same model codes in first column.

I'm looking for code to do this in R or SQL.

Input data:

```
 data<-structure(list(Model.codes = c(960468L, 960468L, 960531L, 960531L, 960531L, 960531L), Item.Ids = c(4072324L, 4072322L, 4072430L, 4072431L, 4072429L, 4072426L)), .Names = c("Model.codes", "Item.Ids" ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output :

```
   Model.codes                          Ids_list
1:      960468                 [4072324,4072322]
2:      960531 [4072430,4072431,4072429,4072426]
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of input data using `dput(head(yourData))` and an example of the expected output?

Comment: Hi @Waldi i have edited my question, attached two images showing input and output, kindly check

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it's better to provide real data on SO than images, that's why I suggested to you to use the dput command on the head of the dataframe you're using. Could you please try this and paste the result in your question instead of images?

Comment: Hi @Waldi, apologies: input: structure(list(Model.codes = c(960468L, 960468L, 960531L, 960531L, 
960531L, 960531L), Item.Ids = c(4072324L, 4072322L, 4072430L, 
4072431L, 4072429L, 4072426L)), .Names = c("Model.codes", "Item.Ids"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Basically, I want to have a LIST of Item codes mapped with Model codes(1st column), let me know if you need any other information. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The output you provided doesn't seem to work : did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this correspond to your needs :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[,.(Ids_list = paste0('[',paste0(Item.Ids,collapse=','),']')),by=Model.codes]

   Model.codes                          Ids_list
1:      960468                 [4072324,4072322]
2:      960531 [4072430,4072431,4072429,4072426]
```

Comment: Hi @waldi, Yes.. but the output is coming in parenthesis, not in square brackets. structure(list(Model.codes = c(960468L, 960531L), Ids_list = list(
    c(4072324L, 4072322L), c(4072430L, 4072431L, 4072429L, 4072426L
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("Model.codes", "Ids_list"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x25bef78>)

Comment: the last step is easier : replaced list by paste, see my edit